How can I properly affix a plastic panel for an ACs exhaust pipe?
I have a portable AC unit in my office and I cannot figure out how to get the plastic panel that sits in the window and holds the exhaust pipe to stay put. I've tried lots of different kind of tape - duct, Gorilla, you name it. And it starts out fine but as soon as the hot weather comes, the heat melts the sticky part of the tape and the panel falls.
My building is quite old, so the window screens don't come out so I have to put the panel between about 1/4 inch of space between the window and the screen to house this plastic panel. Can someone recommend a fix for me? TIA

Can you add pictures to the question: 1) show the whole hose/panel assembly not in the window, without any tape, clearly showing the overall shape and the sides of the panel, and 2) show how the hose is connected to the panel.    It may be possible to screw this panel in before taping, or it may be possible to easily make an alternate panel for the hose that fits better.

Also, regardless of how you solve this, the screen should be open more widely, out of the way, and the panel should be fixed between the window and the frame.  The way you have it, warm air can enter through the screen and open window.

The windows slide in a channels on top and bottom.
Normally those AC vents come with extendable form.
Small clips on the side hold them in place. Remove the clips and extend till it fits in the upper window channel.
Alternatively take two pieces off hard plastic that would overlap in the middle. Cut the opening for the exhausts
Stick one in the upper channel and one in the lover channel and let them overlap.
Screw in the middle (the overlap)
